# If element of array meets condition make it the 1st element

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, conditional-statements

I have a multi-dimensional associative array in php:

```
$myArray = array(
  'a' => array('foo'=>'one', 'bar'=>'two'),
  'b' => array('foo'=>'three', 'bar'=>'four'),
  'c' => array('foo'=>'five', 'bar'=>'six')
);
```

The values of the second level array ('one', 'two', 'three', etc..) are all different.

I would like to go through them and find the one that meets my condition (for example which one is equal to 'three'), and once found, make the correspondig first level key (in that case the 'b' from 'a', 'b', 'c') as the first element of $myArray; while keeping the original order of the other elements.

Additionally, for performance reasons, I would like the code to break out of the loop once one of these keys meets the condition.

So the resulting array should be:

```
myArray (
 [b] => (
  'foo'=>'three',
  'bar'=>'four'
 )
 [a] => (
  'foo'=>'one',
  'bar'=>'two'
 )
 [c] => (
  'foo'=>'five',
  'bar'=>'six'
 )
)
```

I could probably achieve that using uasort, but I have a very large array and so I am looking for the most efficient way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through the array until your target value is found. Break out of the loop after it is found, as you said.

```
$target = 'three';

foreach ($myArray as $key => $value) {
    if ($found = $value['foo'] == $target) break;
}
```

Afterward, if it has been found, you can move the value to the beginning using `array_merge`. (`$key` and `$value` will still be set to the values they had when you broke out of the loop.)

```
if ($found) {
    $myArray = array_merge([$key => $value], $myArray);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly it. I had considered a less elegant approach in  which I would use array_splice() to remove the element then array_merge() to add it at the top. Thank you very much.

Comment: Btw I am going to follow up with another foreach iteration on $myArray; do I need to reset() it or does array_merge() does it?

Comment: Well, if the target is found and the `array_merge` does occur, it will actually be a new array. But either way, you won't need to reset it before another `foreach` loop. That will happen automatically. ([See the note in the `foreach` documentation.](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php))

Comment: Thanks again, you've been very helpful. Cheers!